# Django/Postgres: Returning error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: django, postgresql

I have had this issue occur several times with a project I've been working on, and though I used the "python manage.py sqlsequencereset " fix that I've found on this site, it works for a while, and then begins throwing the error again.

The error I keep getting is pretty straightforward:

```
IntegrityError at /projects/v/portola/planting-sites/new/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "urbanforest_plantingsite_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(194016) already exists.
```

In my view I have:

```
form = PlantingSiteForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    f = form.save(commit=False)
    if PlantingSite.objects.all().exists():
        last_planting_site = PlantingSite.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[0]
        f.id_planting_site = last_planting_site.id_planting_site
        f.id_planting_site += 1
    else:
        f.id_planting_site = 100000
    if request.POST.get('neighborhood_id'):
        f.neighborhood = Neighborhood.objects.filter(id_neighborhood=request.POST.get('neighborhood_id'))[0]
    if request.POST.get('district_id'):
        f.district = District.objects.filter(id_district=request.POST.get('district_id'))[0]
    if request.POST.get('basin_type_id'):
        f.basin_type = BasinType.objects.filter(id_basin_type=request.POST.get('basin_type_id'))[0]
    if request.POST.get('aspect_id'):
        f.aspect = Aspect.objects.filter(id_aspect=request.POST.get('aspect_id'))[0]
    if request.POST.get('orientation_id'):
        f.orientation = Orientation.objects.filter(id_orientation=request.POST.get('orientation_id'))[0]
    if request.POST.get('hardscape_damage_id'):
        f.hardscape_damage = HardscapeDamage.objects.filter(id_hardscape_damage=request.POST.get('hardscape_damage_id'))[0]
    if request.POST.get('status_id'):
        f.status = PlantingSiteStatus.objects.filter(id_planting_site_status=request.POST.get('status_id'))[0]
    else:
        f.status = PlantingSiteStatus.objects.filter(id_planting_site_status=9)[0]
    if f.zipcode:
        f.property_zipcode = f.zipcode
    f.created_by_fuf = True
    f.created_by = request.user 
    f.save()
```

I've done the sqlsequencereset a couple of times now, and then the error returns after a couple of weeks. I'm not importing any data, but my coworkers are using their phone in the field to create new objects, one at a time.

Running sqlsequencereset gets me this code:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"urbanforest_plantingsite"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "urbanforest_plantingsite";
```

Should I be running something more specific? I am not very familiar with Postgres as I've just used Django commands to handle all database calls.

EDIT: One thing to add, I discovered that running sqlsequencereset generates the CODE for adjust the sql call, it does not actually run it. So I ran:
python manage.py sqlsequencereset urbanforest | python manage.py dbshell 
which injected the code and rebuilt the table.

Unfortunately, I received the same error a few minutes later.

Comment: You have a race condition; if two persons try to create a `PlantingSite` at the same time, they get the same ID. Why are you incrementing the IDs manually? Also, just from glancing at the code, it seems that a lot of what you're doing could be done by the form's `save`.

Comment: There are only two folks using the app in the field, and they're rarely there at the same time, so hopefully a race condition isn't a problem now, I'm not sure what to do to fix that long term. For the incrementing IDs, I just wanted a public-facing ID that wasn't directly connected to PKs, just in case.

Comment: It may not be a race condition, if the object returned by `order_by('-created_at')` is not necessarily the one with highest ID. Unless you have a good reason for manual IDs, it's just creating pain for nothing. You can use `F` expressions or `select_for_update` to account for concurrency, and make the query in a different way to make sure it really gets the highest ID, but it seems superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this (at least for now) by moving site creation in to a while loop. I think the issue is how Django handles creating objects by using model forms. Since you create the object and save it to memory with form.save(commit=False), you can run into problems because it's adding those other fields to the object before committing it to the database.

So for now, at least, this has solved the problem:

```
while True:
        try:    
            form = PlantingSiteForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    f = form.save(commit=False)
                    if PlantingSite.objects.all().exists():
                        last_planting_site = PlantingSite.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[0]
                        f.id_planting_site = last_planting_site.id_planting_site
                        f.id_planting_site += 1
                    else:
                        f.id_planting_site = 100000
                    if request.POST.get('neighborhood_id'):
                        f.neighborhood = Neighborhood.objects.filter(id_neighborhood=request.POST.get('neighborhood_id'))[0]
                    if request.POST.get('district_id'):
                        f.district = District.objects.filter(id_district=request.POST.get('district_id'))[0]
                    if request.POST.get('basin_type_id'):
                        f.basin_type = BasinType.objects.filter(id_basin_type=request.POST.get('basin_type_id'))[0]
                    if request.POST.get('aspect_id'):
                        f.aspect = Aspect.objects.filter(id_aspect=request.POST.get('aspect_id'))[0]
                    if request.POST.get('orientation_id'):
                        f.orientation = Orientation.objects.filter(id_orientation=request.POST.get('orientation_id'))[0]
                    if request.POST.get('hardscape_damage_id'):
                        f.hardscape_damage = HardscapeDamage.objects.filter(id_hardscape_damage=request.POST.get('hardscape_damage_id'))[0]
                    if request.POST.get('status_id'):
                        f.status = PlantingSiteStatus.objects.filter(id_planting_site_status=request.POST.get('status_id'))[0]
                    else:
                        f.status = PlantingSiteStatus.objects.filter(id_planting_site_status=9)[0]
                    if f.zipcode:
                        f.property_zipcode = f.zipcode
                    f.created_by_fuf = True
                    f.created_by = request.user 
                    f.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            sleep(random.uniform(0.001, 0.5)) # chill out, try again
            messages.success(request, "Still creating previous site, trying again...")
            continue
```

So it tries to create the object, if it fails due to integrity error it sleeps for a hot second, then tries again. So far, so good, my coworkers are using it in the field and i haven't seen any errors yet.